# windows sp2 support setx license

Tags: windows, licensing, windows-xp

Can i use setx tool that is provided by "XP SP2 Support tools" for our product
installer? We want to set environment variables.
[There are about 30 items in the update for windows XP ]

I am unsure of the licensing information about using just this one tool in our product Installer. or is there an alternative.

Please advise.

Regards
Vish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't distribute setx so you would have to rely on it being present of the target system. I strongly recommend you use a dedicated tool to build your installer rather than trying to do it with a .bat file.

Comment: David, I presume there is a supported way for MSI files to set environment variables?